C++17: Alignment of a second column of text
I have seen several similar questions, but haven't found any that quite answers what I need, and most of these use std::cout along with iomanip
I'm using libfmt (although a c++20 answer would likely be compatible)
What I have is a statement similar to the following:
std::string{fmt::format(
"Found system paths:\n"
"{8}base: {0}\n"
"{8}share: {1}\n"
"{8}locale: {2}\n"
"{8}sysConf: {3}\n"
"{8}home: {4}\n"
"{8}config: {5}\n"
"{8}data: {6}\n"
"{8}cache: {7}\n",
base, share, locale, sysConf, home, conf, data, cache, "|----------"
)};

The purpose of {8} is to compensate for a prefix added to the first line of output after fmt is done with it.
The problem is, since both the actual paths and the name of each folder have different widths, I cannot get it to align neatly.
What I'd want to see would be something like:
----------- Found system paths
|---------- base:         /path/to/somewhere/base
|---------- share:        /path/to/base/share
|---------- locale:       /path/to/base/locale
|---------- sysConf:      /path/to/another-place/config
|---------- home:         /path/to/home
|---------- config:       /path/to/a-third-place/config
|---------- data:         /path/to/base/data
|---------- cache:        /path/to/a-third-place/cache


I am aware of alignment/width syntax, but haven't figured out how to use them to accomplish what I want., which is why I've omitted any use of them in the code (I've tried several different failed combinations in the actual code)

a [mcve] would help to see what your code does, to fix it, and to validate potential answers.

As prefix is known, alignment can be done manually ("{8}base:         {0}\n"), no?

How about using tabs (\t) ?

Tabs don't work for some reason. Manually aligning with spaces does, but I was hoping for something better.

So what you'd really like is for fmt to look at the string literal you pass, pick out some substrings, find the longest of those, then format each of them with the width of the longest one (plus a little padding).
I'm pretty sure it simply can't do that. If somebody wanted to badly enough, it would be possible to define something that was otherwise similar to format that supported that, but as things are, it's simply not supported.
If you want to find the widths of those strings and format them all with the correct width, you're going to have to 1) find the width you want, and 2) specify that width for a value that you pass in.
#include <format>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::size_t max_len(std::vector<std::string> const &strings) {
    std::size_t max_len = 0;
    for (auto const &s : strings)
        if (s.length() > max_len)
            max_len = s.length();       
    return max_len;
}

std::string get_path(std::string const &input) { 
    return "/path/to/" + input;
}

int main() { 
    std::vector<std::string> labels {
        "base:",
        "share:",
        "locale:",
        "sysConf:",
        "home:",
        "config:",
        "data:",
        "cache:"
    };

    auto width = max_len(labels) + 1;

    for (auto const &label : labels)
        std::cout << std::format("{}{:{}}{}\n", "|----------", label, width, get_path(label));
}

Probably not what you really wanted to hear, but I don't see much of an alternative, unless you're willing to do some hacking on the fmt library.
If I were going to do that, you could specify an "inline argument" by enclosing it it curly braces, and specify the width for each, or a special character to indicate setting them all to the same width.
"Found system paths:\n"
"{8}{{M0}base:} {0}\n"
"{8}{{M0}share:} {1}\n"
"{8}{{M0}locale:} {2}\n"
"{8}{{M0}sysConf:} {3}\n"
"{8}{{M0}home:} {4}\n"
"{8}{{M0}config:} {5}\n"
"{8}{{M0}data:} {6}\n"
"{8}{{M0}cache:} {7}\n"

So in this nonexistent library, M would mean "maximum". the 0 is simply a group number, so M0 means "maximum width of items in group 0`. So if you had multiple items like this, you'd use a different number for each.
But as I said, that doesn't exist--and unless you want it pretty badly, chances are pretty good that it never will either...

What you are looking for is: {:{}}
You can use it like this: std::format("{:{}}END", "Text", 20);
This will make Text 20 characters long:
Text                END
So in this case you need to calculate the length of the longest folder name, and pass that as a parametr:

const auto folder_name_align_len = calc_max_folder_name_len(...);

const auto text = std::format(
"Found system paths:\n"
"{0}{2:{1}}: {3}\n"
"{0}{4:{1}}: {5}\n"
"{0}{6:{1}}: {7}\n"
...,

"|----------",
folder_name_align_len,

base_folder_name, full_base_name,
share_folder_name, full_share_name,
locale_folder_name, full_locale_name,
... 
);

That has the disadvantage of aligning the : right before the full folder name.
To solve this you can add the : directly into the folder name:
"{0}{2:{1}}{3}\n"
...
folder_name_align_len + 2, // add the length of additional text
...
base_folder_name + ": ", full_base_name,


Why not simply align the 2nd column the way you want directly in your format string?
std::string{fmt::format(
"Found system paths:\n"
"{8}base:    {0}\n"
"{8}share:   {1}\n"
"{8}locale:  {2}\n"
"{8}sysConf: {3}\n"
"{8}home:    {4}\n"
"{8}config:  {5}\n"
"{8}data:    {6}\n"
"{8}cache:   {7}\n",
base, share, locale, sysConf, home, conf, data, cache, "|----------"
)};

If you want more control over the spacing, then you can do something more like this:
std::string{fmt::format(
"Found system paths:\n"
"{0}{2:{1}}{3}\n"
"{0}{4:{1}}{5}\n"
"{0}{6:{1}}{7}\n"
"{0}{8:{1}}{9}\n"
"{0}{10:{1}}{11}\n"
"{0}{12:{1}}{13}\n"
"{0}{14:{1}}{15}\n"
"{0}{16:{1}}{17}\n",
"|----------",
14,
"base:", base,
"share:", share,
"locale:", locale,
"sysConf:", sysConf,
"home:", home,
"config:", conf,
"data:", data,
"cache:", cache
)};


I was hoping for a programmatic approach because I have several other similar but not exactly identical cases.

@GregorioLitenstein that seems to be a very important bit of information that should be in the question. I recommend adding it before you get more correct-but-useless-to-you answers.
